# Why the recursive list is so slow in haskell？

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am fresh in haskell, and I defined a func in Haskell :

```
febs :: (Integral a)=> a -> a
febs n 
    | n<=0 =0
    | n==1 =1
    | n==2 =1
    | otherwise =febs(n-1)+febs(n-2)
```

but, it runs so slow, and when I do "febs 30", it will take about 10s, 
and I do the same func in C++, it runs very fast.

```
int febs(int n)
{
    if(n == 1 || n ==2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return febs(n-1)+febs(n-2);
}
```

Is there any way to promote my haskell func speed?

Comment: That function is traditionally called "fib" or "fibs" because it gives you the *Fibonacci* numbers. Just getting my pedantry out of the way :P.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is an odd comparison, for the following reasons:

1. You don't say whether you're compiling the Haskell code, or with what options. If you're just running it in ghci, then of course it will be slow - you're comparing interpreted code with compiled code.
2. Your Haskell code is polymorphic whereas your C++ code is monomorphic (that is, you've used a type class `Integral a => a -> a` instead of the concrete type `Int -> Int`). Your Haskell code is therefore more general than your C++ code, because it can handle arbitrarily large integers instead of being restricted to the range of an `Int`. It's possible that the compiler will optimize this away, but I'm not certain.

If I put the following code in a file fib.hs

```
fibs :: Int -> Int
fibs n = if n < 3 then 1 else fibs (n-1) + fibs (n-2)

main = print (fibs 30)
```

and compile it with `ghc -O2 fib.hs` then it runs fast enough that it appears instantaneous to me. You should try that, and see how it compares with the C++ code.

Comment: Regarding the polymorphism: does that really have an effect in this case? I'd guess that the function would get inlined or something when you use it, but I'm not an expert. (Assuming you have optimizations on.) Oh, and assuming it has the `Int` type at the call site. Which, thinking about it, isn't a fair assumption.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure. I suppose you have to look at the Core, but I'm not experienced enough to do that!

Comment: Actually, I could just run both versions (with both signatures) and compare the running time. And by "I", I really mean "you" because I'd have to boot into Linux :P.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis It plays a role. Since it's recursive, it can't be inlined. When compiling with optimisations (always assuming GHC), if it's used monomorphically in the same source file as it's defined, you'll get a specialisation. Without type signature, in `main` that'd be at `Integer`, so somewhat slower than with `Int`. If you define it in a different file than it's used in, unless you make it `{-# INLINABLE #-}`, you get the very slow polymorphic code.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That's exactly what I was wondering about. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use the Int, and it will be faster. and I tried to use python shell to do this job, and it is a little faster than which in GHCi.

Comment: @aasa If you compile with `-O2`, it's not just "a little" faster, it's a huge difference (okay, gcc -O3 is still about three times as fast).

Comment: @Daniel Fischer You are right, I tried -o2 and -o3, it runs faster a lot.

Comment: @aasa, make sure you're using -O2 not -o2. Also, those asking about inlining, I'm pretty sure GHC won't inline the definition because it's a recursive function. I could be wrong however; Check the Core!

Answer (score 13):

Try compiling with optimization. With GHC 7.4.1 with -O2, your program runs quite quickly:

```
$ time ./test 
832040

real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.000s
```

This is with `main = print (febs 30)`.

---

Regarding the polymorphism considerations in Chris Taylor's answer, here's `febs 40` with OP's polymorphic Fibonacci function:

```
$ time ./test 
102334155

real    0m5.670s
user    0m5.652s
sys     0m0.004s
```

And here is a non-polymorphic one, i.e. with OP's signature replaced with `Int -> Int`:

```
$ time ./test 
102334155

real    0m0.820s
user    0m0.816s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Per Tikhon Jelvis' comment, it'd be interesting to see if the speedup is due to replacing `Integer` with `Int`, or due to getting rid of polymorphism. Here's the same program again, except with `febs` moved to a new file per Daniel Fischer's comment, and with with `febs :: Integer -> Integer`:

```
$ time ./test 
102334155

real    0m5.648s
user    0m5.624s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Again, with `febs` in a different file, and with the same polymorphic signature as originally:

```
$ time ./test 
102334155

real    0m16.610s
user    0m16.469s
sys     0m0.104s
```

Comment: Thanks for testing the polymorphic vs monomorphic versions (I'm running Windows, so getting the runtime is a pain!)

Comment: An `Integral` type gets defaulted to `Integer`. I'm curious if the change in performance is just because of `Integer` vs `Int` or if the polymorphism also matters.

Comment: You had the function defined in the same file as `main` hadn't you? In separate files, with polymorphic code, I get a running time of 15.5s for `febs 40`, 5.4s for `Integer -> Integer` and 0.86s for `Int -> Int`. @TikhonJelvis this would answer your question. And 0.3s for gcc -O3.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah, you're right. I read too quickly. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielFischer: I guess this is off topic now, but here's a question: If you have lots and lots of polymorphism scattered over many files, but in the end you end up calling these with only a handful of actual types, is there a way to tell GHC something like "I want to define this function, with this concrete signature, and I want all the polymorphic functions it calls specialized"?

Comment: You have to tell GHC at the definition site that the function either should be specialised for some types (`{-# SPECIALISE foo :: Int -> Int, Word -> Integer #-}` [US spelling also accepted]), or - requires GHC >= 7 [perhaps 7.2, not sure] - with an `{-# INLINABLE foo #-}` pragma that it should expose the function for inlining/optimising/specialising in the interface file. Then (always with -O2) it will be done automatically, at least if the nesting isn't too deep [I can imagine that the optimiser gives up if your call-tree is 1000 polymorphic functions deep].

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you! I'm sure you've saved me quite some time with this comment. I've heard about `INLINABLE` before, but always thought it had to do with, well, just inlining. Is `SPECIALIZE` superfluous if `INLINABLE` is available?

Comment: Generally, yes. With `INLINABLE`, a specialised version is generated at the use site. If you use a polymorphic function at one specific type in a lot of modules, each gets its own specialised version, then it can be preferable to use a `SPECIALISE` pragma to reduce (compiled) code size.

Answer (score 3):

You could also write the function like this:

```
fibs = 0:1:zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

It is very fast, even for big 'n' executes immediately:

```
Prelude> take 1000 fibs
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's asymptotically different. I think the real question was about comparing C++ to Haskell, so using a different algorithm would be out. It is good advice in general though.

Comment: Or, to be even cooler, like this: `fibs = 0 : scanl (+) 1 fibs`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is a wonderful solution, and I can feel the power of haskell from these codes.

Comment: @Ed'ka Why stop half way? `fix ((0:) . scanl (+) 1)`.

Comment: I saw a really nice one the other day: `let fibs@(t:fibs') = 1:zipWith (+) fibs fibs' in fibs

Comment: @Axman6 This actually is the same code hask wrote with the `tail` replaced by an at-pattern.

Comment: @FUZxxl, I know, it's just a slightly more elegant way of doing it imo.

Comment: @DanielFischer it depends which `fix` is used there, `fix f = f (fix f)` or `fix f = let x = f x in x `. with the 1st we're in for a not-so-pleasant surprise. Fortunately, `Data.Function` uses the 2nd, of course. :)